# Is there a way to cache a string fragment within a helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a helper that generates complex HTML for common components in an engine.

Helper (very simplified):

```
def component(name)
  component = Component.find_by_name!(name)
  # a whole lot of complex stuff that uses component to build some HTML
end
```

View:

```
<%= component(:my_component) %>
```

I want to implement fragment caching on these components but I want to do it within `#component` itself to keep things DRY, e.g.

```
def component(name)
  ...

  cache some_unique_fragment_name do
    html
  end

  # or, more succinctly:
  cache(some_unique_fragment_name, html)
end
```

The problem is that Rails' [cache](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CacheHelper/cache) helper expects it's going to wrap a block of HTML in Erb and therefore won't work as I've described above.

Is there a way to use `#cache` for a string fragment in a helper method?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of the `fetch` block, you can read more in the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch):

```
def component(name)
  # ...

  cache.fetch('some_unique_fragment_name') do
    html
  end
end
```

What this does is it will return the value of `some_unique_fragment_name` if it's available, otherwise it will generate it inside the block. It's a readable, clean way of showing that caching is occurring.